# Register AWS Redshift activity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-lambda

As per AWS docs, there's no Redshift-Lambda integration yet.
What we would like to do is monitoring redshift activity in order to do something when a redshift table is created, a copy from S3 is made or a bulk insert is performed.
Is there a way to register this kind of activity, and then do something similar to run a lambda function ir order run a small script or so?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift provides an event notification mechanism.  You can find a full list of the event categories and messages [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-event-notifications.html).  If that covers the kind of information you are interested in you can simply have your Lambda function add the SNS topic used by Redshift for event notification as an event source and your Lambda function will get called every time an event is sent by Redshift.

Comment: It seems that this event notification mechanism is related to management, config and monitoring stuff. What we need is to check that a particular query or copy from S3 has been made, and based on that, do something. We are working on a python script that checks stl_query table, within a cron expression or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [audit logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/db-auditing.html) that end up in s3.

All the info you want is also available in [various admin tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_system-tables.html) with prefixes like `stl_`, `stv_` and `pg_`. For example, `COPY` commands from S3 are recorded in [stl_load_commits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html), and [stl_utilitytext](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_UTILITYTEXT.html) has info on non-select queries like `CREATE`.

As for triggering events, you could have [S3 trigger a lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) when one of the log files lands or run occasional jobs that query the system tables and take action with something like cron jobs or [airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow).